# How to display Jquery autocomplete result outside autocomplete function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This HTML code is for picking a date and a destination for the trip. I want to display my result (Destination) outside the autocomplete function.

How to call autocomplete result in `confirm` box (check `if else` statement in jquery)?

Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pick a Date</title>
         <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="style/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="script/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="script/1.10.3-jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script/script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h2><br/>Select a Destination</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <p>Departing: <input type="text" id="departing"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Returning: <input type="text" id="returning"></p>
        </div><br/>
        <div id="main">
        <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Destination: </label>
        <input id="tags">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#departing").datepicker();
    $("#returning").datepicker();
    $("button").click(function() {
        var departing = $("#departing").val();
        var returning = $("#returning").val();
        var places = ["Canada","China","Chicago","Japan","Germany","London","Moskow","Paris","Phillipins","India","Russia","Srilanka"];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: places,
    select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#tags').text(ui.item.value);
                }
  });
        if (departing === "" || returning === "") {
            alert("Please select departing and returning dates.");
        } else {
            confirm("Would you like to go to " + ???? + " on " + departing + " and return on " + returning + "?");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 confirm("Would you like to go to " + jQuery( '#tags' ).val() + " on " + departing + " and return on " + returning + "?");
```

What it does:
After the user choosed a destination, this is showen in the . So we have to read the Input-Value.

We access the Input-Object by jQuery( '#tags' ). Now we ask for the falue by .val(). This returns us the value of the Input-field.

More information:
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Ah, and because this might cause some irritation

jQuery( '#tags' ) equals $( '#tags' )

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked!! Can you give little insight about your answer please, as jquery is new for me.